# How to continuously output the seconds since the start of a calculation with C?

Tags: c++, c, time, timer, clock

I'm trying to code a 'live' timer that runs during a calculation. It should continuously output the seconds since the start of the calculation - something like a progress bar. I did this so far:

```c
#include <conio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    clock_t t;
    t = clock();

    while (!_kbhit())
    {
        t = clock() - t;
        printf("%f", ((float)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
        system("cls");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

But there are a few problems:

- It's flickering due to the call of `system("cls")`.
- The time is by far not correct due to the continuous call of `printf()`

Is there a rather easy way of doing this with C?

Comment: What @H2CO3 said. Plus, if you don't want flicker, don't use `cls`. Just do the first `printf`, then do something like a CR (`\\r`) or backspaces to overwrite the the number on the screen on each iteration. Or uses a `curses` library.

Comment: would it be possible without multithreading?

Comment: Actually depends on what is done as the actual action. If that is something that can be done with async system calls, then you could as well just print the progress in the main thread, but if you need something blocking then you need multithreading. As for the blinking, printing carriage return should do fine to move the text pointer to the start of the line. If it is just something mathematical, you can approximate how often it is sensible to update the progress and still print it in the same thread as the calcualtion.

Comment: You said that the result is not correct but are you sure `t = clock() - t` is what you want here? What results did you get and what were you expecting?

Comment: Does it really have to be that accurate? Surely just an indication that something is happening and it has not stalled  might be sufficient. If so then just place updates to the task bar in various locations.

Comment: Without multithreading you could do event-based. There are for example libraries to help with this, see libevent for setting up event handlers to let your progress bar update e.g. every 100 ms and the calculation to occur continuously

Answer (score 0):

One very simple and not ideal way would be to simply stop printing so frequently, so here is an untested code as example to print the time once every INTERVAL clocks.

```
#define INTERVAL 1000
int main(void)
{
   clock_t t;
   t = clock();
   clock_t step_time = INTERVAL;

   while (!_kbhit())
   {
      t = clock() - t;
      if (t - step_time > INTERVAL){
         step_time = t + INTERVAL;
         printf("%f", ((float)t) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
         system("cls");
      }
   }    
return 0;
}
```

You can change the INTERVAL to something smaller

Comment: `t = clock() - t` is going to act like a toggle switch once the value of `t` reaches a certain value. This is only going to reduce the calls to `printf` by 50%.